# npm install in Django Docker file

Tags: django, docker

I am working with Django and currently try to move my local dev. to Docker. I managed to run my web server. However, what I didn't to yet was `npm install`. That's where I got stuck and I couldn't find documentation or good examples. Anyone who has done that before?

**Dockerfile**:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.7

# Define environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    # Language dependencies
    gettext \
    # In addition, when you clean up the apt cache by removing /var/lib/apt/lists
    # it reduces the image size, since the apt cache is not stored in a layer.
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --dev

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      # Password will be required if connecting from a different host
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=django

  web:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: django
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Apply database migrations
echo "Apply database migrations"
python manage.py migrate

# Run tests (In progress)
# echo "Running tests"
# pytest

# Start server
echo "Starting server"
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: What do you need `npm` for? Frontend? Build it in prod mode and deploy as static files.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, you should just follow this instruction:

```
npm install

//or

yarn install
```

This will install all node_modules, when it is not found in the current directory, it will search for the **node_modules** on directory up.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dockerfile just add:
RUN npm install

This will look if there is a package.json in the current directory and if it does, it will install all dependencies.

Comment: Is it not necessary to install Node.js through an image?